# Force refresh site in old tab when user open new tab with different account

Tags: javascript, php, asp.net, cookies

This is my client website case,

User login with admin account in Tab 1 (old tab) and he has menu:

- menu form A
- menu form B
- menu form C

Then he open new tab -> logout -> login with regular account in Tab 2 (new tab) and he has menu:

- menu form A
- menu form B

Anyway, in old tab he still can open **menu C**.

I know it's better to put security check in every form. But I need more time for that. Can we force the old tab to refresh or logout automatically? Do you have any simple idea? I kindly accept it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can program an ajax call to periodically check whether the user is still logged. Changes won't be reflected at the same moment the user logs off in the other tab, that will depend on how often you make the calls.

Comment: i got your idea, now i have javascript function to check between session and cookie. I create cookie when user login and read cookie periodically to compare it.